# PHP Json format variable declaration

Tags: php, json

I am using paypal api to get the payee information.
I am getting the json result. how to get the `email`, `first_name`,`last_name` different variable

Here is the JSON result:

```
{
    id: "PAY-4L2624428H450980CLD23F4A",
    intent: "sale",
    state: "approved",
    cart: "74345738MA858411Y",
    payer: {
        payment_method: "paypal",
        status: "VERIFIED",
        payer_info: {
            email: "haj.mohamed-facilitator@pmgasia.com",
            first_name: "test",
            last_name: "facilitator",
            payer_id: "Z2ZSX2WM9ALD2",
            shipping_address: {
                recipient_name: "test facilitator"
            },
            country_code: "SG"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using Google you would have found the PHP function [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), which converts, if the second parameter is set to `true`, will return the JSON as an associative array.

Comment: given json is not an valid json please check [ http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ ]

Answer (score 1):

Use json_decode and use foreach loop using you will get all the data with key and value.

```
  $json = "{id: "PAY-4L2624428H450980CLD23F4A",intent: "sale",state: "approved",cart: "74345738MA858411Y",
   payer: {payment_method: "paypal",status: "VERIFIED",payer_info: {email: "haj.mohamed-facilitator@pmgasia.com",first_name: 
   "test",last_name: "facilitator",payer_id: "Z2ZSX2WM9ALD2",shipping_address: {recipient_name: "test facilitator"},country_code: "SG"}}";

 $temp = json_encode($json);

 foreach ($temp as $key=>$value) 
 {
 // $key and  $value
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to decode json string into object or array. if your result in `$json_str` variable then,

```
$result_arr= json_decode($json_str, true) // returns in array
$result_obj= json_decode($json_str) // returns in object
```

for more detail http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

@Haj Mohamed A first of all your json is invalid since the keys id, intent etc are not double quoted so as the php perspective this json is invalid, if you do `json_decode($json_str, true)` then you will get `null` value so you have to arrange this json like:

```
<?php
  $json_string = '{
                   "id":"PAY-4L2624428H450980CLD23F4A",
                   "intent":"sale",
                   "state":"approved",
                   "cart":"74345738MA858411Y",
                   "payer":{
                      "payment_method":"paypal",
                      "status":"VERIFIED",
                      "payer_info":{
                         "email":"haj.mohamed-facilitator@pmgasia.com",
                         "first_name":"test",
                         "last_name":"facilitator",
                         "payer_id":"Z2ZSX2WM9ALD2",
                         "shipping_address":{
                            "recipient_name":"test facilitator"
                         },
                         "country_code":"SG"
                      }
                   }
                }';
  $infoArr = json_decode($json_string, true);

  //1.Now you can use foreach():

                    //or 2.you can directly get the value by array index like below;
 echo "email : ".$infoArr["payer"]["payer_info"]["email"]."<br>";
 echo "first_name : ".$infoArr["payer"]["payer_info"]["first_name"]."<br>";
 echo "last_name : ".$infoArr["payer"]["payer_info"]["last_name"]."<br>";
```